# Laravel 5.1 created_at timestamp being automatically changed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I've got a laravel project that is running fine on my local version of Google app engine, however when deployed the created_at timestamp is being changed even though it is set not to.

All of my models have

```
 public $timestamps = false;
```

as I need to update certain parts of the row without affecting the timestamps, so I do this manually.

In my repository I have the following function:

```
public function setLock($id)
{
    $row = $this->model->find($id);
    if(!$row){
        return null;
    }
    $row->timestamps = false;
    if($row->locked_at == NULL || strtotime($row->locked_at) < strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) || $row->locked_by == Auth::id()){
        try{
            $row->locked_by   = Auth::id();
            $row->locked_at   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+5 min"));
            $row->save();
            return true;
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            Log::error('Error setting lock at ID:' .$id.': ' . $e->getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Which still updates the created_at timestamp, regardless of if the timestamp variable is set or not, both within the model and the function.

I've also tried setting this function inside the model:

```
public function setUpdatedAt($value)
{
   //Do-nothing
}
```

But still, it updates..

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: have you checked the column in the table? it can also be the cause

Comment: @BinaryGhost The created_at column is set to timestamp, not null. Is this what it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like we discussed in the comments, its the database who is changing the create_at each time the row is updated.

You can remove the default value for the 'create_at' column,

Or you can send the original created_at each time you update the row. this way you will be able to keep the original creation date.

**Edit**

If you decided to set the deafult value to null, make sure that when you insert new rows you update them with the date and time.

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I missed this... On the local no 'on update' is set, however on the deployed application it is.. for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check created_at field attribute in table. if its set to 'on Update current timestamp' then change to empty.

I think it may be help full for you.